# L4.2 Extend/override Cashier to add Tax feature

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 4.2 with Cashier and I need to modify its protected function buildPayload() but I don't want to do it directly in the vendor file as I could break the code when I composer Update... How should I proceed to override this function with my own Logic ?

I currently use Cashier in one of my controller by doing:

```
$user->subscription('testplan')
                    ->create(Input::get('stripeToken'), [
                        'email' => 'email@email.com,
                    ]);
```

But I want to add a withTax() parameters...
Like so:

```
$user->subscription('testplan')
                        ->withTax(10)
                        ->create(Input::get('stripeToken'), [
                            'email' => 'email@email.com,
                        ]);
```

I already know how to do it directly in the `StripeGateway.php` file but it's bad practice...

I know that I need to add:

```
protected $taxPercent = 0;

    public function withTax($tax)
    {
        $this->taxPercent = $tax;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function buildPayload()
    {
        $payload = [
            'plan' => $this->plan, 'prorate' => $this->prorate,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity, 'trial_end' => $this->getTrialEndForUpdate(),
            'tax_percent' => $this->taxPercent,
        ];

        return $payload;
    }
```

What I don't know is how to add this code not directly in the Cashier Original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find how to do it by myself, it's first time I do this kind of thing... Please correct me if my method is wrong!

First:

I created a Folder named **Lib\Cashier** like so: **laravel/app/Lib/Cashier**

I then created 2 files: **BillableTrait.php** and **NewStripeGateway.php**

**BillableTrait.php** code:

```
<?php namespace Lib\Cashier;

use Laravel\Cashier;
use Lib\Cashier\NewStripeGateway as StripeGateway;

trait BillableTrait {
    use Cashier\BillableTrait;

    /**
     * Get a new billing gateway instance for the given plan.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Cashier\PlanInterface|string|null  $plan
     * @return \Laravel\Cashier\StripeGateway
     */
    public function subscription($plan = null)
    {
        if ($plan instanceof PlanInterface) $plan = $plan->getStripeId();

        return new StripeGateway($this, $plan);
    }


}
```

For **NewStripeGateway.php**:

```
<?php namespace Lib\Cashier;

use Laravel\Cashier\StripeGateway;

class NewStripeGateway extends StripeGateway {

    protected $taxPercent = 0;

    public function withTax($tax)
    {
        $this->taxPercent = $tax;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function buildPayload()
    {
        $payload = [
            'plan' => $this->plan, 'prorate' => $this->prorate,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity, 'trial_end' => $this->getTrialEndForUpdate(),
            'tax_percent' => $this->taxPercent,
        ];

        return $payload;
    }
}
```

And then I edited my Model that use Cashier like so (only changed the USE block):

```
use Lib\Cashier\BillableTrait;
use Laravel\Cashier\BillableInterface;
```

I can now do this directly to set the tax on a subscription:

```
$user->subscription('testplan')
                        ->withTax(10)
                        ->create(Input::get('stripeToken'), [
                            'email' => 'email@email.com',
                        ]);
```

It's working perfectly!! If there is anything I did wrong, please notice me of the changes, it's first time I dig in PHP classes (traits, extends, etc) by myself..

Thank you!

Raphael

Comment: Yes,the only thing I would change is not trying to make it look like the original (`use Lib\Cashier\NewStripeGateway as StripeGateway;`) I would leave it as 'NewStripeGateway' and then instead of `new StripeGateway` you would do `new NewStripeGateway`. also you could override the `subscription` method in your user model [in case you only use the Billable trait once] but what you did is probably more organized. [just wanted to mention that its not the only way to override trait]

Answer (score 0):

You could add `getTaxPercent` method in your `user` model and it will calculate the taxes as well.[Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/billing#subscription-taxes)

sadly there's no option to extend the `StripeGateway` class as its hard coded in the `Billable` trait,what you can do is change those functions -

`public function charge($amount, array $options = [])
    {
        return (new StripeGateway($this))->charge($amount, $options);
    }
    public function subscription($plan = null)
    {
        return new StripeGateway($this, $plan);
    }`

in your `user` class,the problem here is that you can never know what would change in the `Billable`,they might change the name of functions and add few more that uses the `StripeGateway` and you wouldn't know until the bugs will arrive.

The first option would probably be much better as you wont need to mention `withTax` method each time.

Comment: Do you know if it will work even with the Cashier v2.0.7 that is compatible with Laravel 4.2? The docs concerning tax are for Laravel 5/Cashier v5

Comment: it doesnt seem like anyone going to update [Laravel/cashier 2.0](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/tree/2.0) and from the sources over there it doesnt seem like it support this method. I dont see any reason why not updating to 5.1,yes its not a simple task but this is the only way you will stay up to date there are few nice new features and also it is much more organized then 4.X. if thats not an option so I would go for the method overriding and extending the `StripeGateway` class and add your `withTax` method

Comment: I will do the overriding/extending 'option' as passing to 5.1 is not really an option for me at the moment... I will simply block the update to v2.0.7 in my composer.json to be sure that no changes will append in future... But my initial question is exactly "how" to do that.. I know that I must extend/override but I don't know how to do that, I am not comfortable enough with PHP to know what to do exactly, could you give me simple details on how to do that and I will mark your precise answer as correct ;) Thank-you Gal